# Start a service as soon as possible after app installs, but not again?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to get a service to start as soon as possible after the app has been installed to get some initial data. Then I update the data every few days using an alarm.

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to start the service on first app run, but not on the second. Any ideas?

Comment: Store whether the service has been started in a SharedPreference.  If it has been, don't start it again.

Comment: By started, do you mean the first time a user opens an `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SharedPreferences` to identify if it is the "**First time**" the app is launched. Just use a Boolean variable ("is_first_time") and change its value to false when your task for "first time" is over.

This is the code to catch the first time you open the app:

```
     final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        if (settings.getBoolean("is_first_time", true)) {
            //the app is being launched for first time, Start your service here      

            settings.edit().putBoolean("is_first_time", false).commit(); 
  }
```

Comment: I actually implemented this using sql with a table (key text primary key, value text) to use as my makeshift key/value store. However, this would work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple options to start your service when the application is started, installed, or a device is booted.

1. Make your own subclass of `Application` and override [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29)
   and call [startService(Intent i)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29).
2. Start your `Service` when an `Activity` is [created](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) you can use `startService`.
3. Start at boot time using this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332744/start-a-service-as-soon-as-possible-after-app-installs-but-not-again).
4. Use an `IntentFilter` in the `Android Manifest` to received your own [installation events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Just do a word search on "install".

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, but #4 was a really cool thing. I had no idea there were so many events for so many things.